# Wrapping all native functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, word-wrap

Since functions get deprecated and sometimes you just find a better way to do something I was wondering if it's a good or a bad idea to wrapp all native functions in PHP to a class of my own. For example:

```
class PHPFUNC {
 public static function f_strrev($string) {
    return strrev($string);
  }
}
```

And using them like:

```
PHPFUNC::f_strrev($string);
```

Instead of:

```
strrev($string);
```

This way I could easily change all function calls simultaneously and I could swap between mb_ versions and normal ones easily too.

What do you think? Pros? Cons? Does this create a lot of overhead?

Comment: Programming to an interface is generally a good idea, but you might slightly lose some performance because of the invocation chain here. So, it would be a trade-off. Many would make the argument that if a function changed so drastically that it's arguments/name etc changed, then you should probably re-evaluate any code that used it.

Comment: Yeah I tend to agree. One major downside would be slowing my coding down a lot!

Comment: It shouldn't slow your code down that much unless you have something like 100k+ walls, I think. How many walls on average does your map have? You could implement a `QuadTree`, or an `R-Tree` if you have that many walls. That way you'd only iterate walls that are in range.

Comment: How often do you actually need to swap a native function in your projects? I doubt there is a real use case of dumping functions in some wrapper class.